# Produce same result as CryptoJS.enc.Base64 using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, cryptography, cryptojs

I have a javascript function that I'm trying to convert to PHP, It uses CryptoJS library, speciafically `components/enc-base64-min.js` and `rollups/md5.js`. They can be found [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/crypto-js).

In it is this bit of code

```
// Let's say str = 'hello';

var md5 = CryptoJS.MD5(str);
md5 = md5.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
// md5 outputs "XUFAKrxLKna5cZ2REBfFkg=="
```

I assumed the `str` variable is hashed using md5 then encoded to Base64, so I tried this simple code

```
$md5 = md5($str);
$md5 = base64_encode($md5);
// md5 outputs "MmZjMGE0MzNiMjg4MDNlNWI5NzkwNzgyZTRkNzdmMjI="
```

Then I tried validating both the outputs, looks like the JS output isnt even a valid Base64 string.

To understand further I tried to look for `toString()` parameter from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp), but it doesnt make sense to me, as per the reference the parameter is supposed to be an integer (2, 8 or 16), then why is `CryptoJS.enc.Base64` used instead?

My goal here isn't to produce a valid base64 encoded string using JS but rather to produce the same output using PHP.

Comment: MD5 produces a 16-byte binary output. Base 64 encodes each 6-bits into an 8-bit ASCII character. 16*8/6 = 21.3 bytes and Base64 pads the output to a 4-byte multiple. This MD5 output base64 encoded will produce 24 bytes of output, that agrees with the first example. The second example produces 44 bytes of output and is thus incorrect.

Comment: @zaph Thanks for the elaborated clarification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

php's `md5()` with a single parameter returns the md5 hash **as a hex string**.

Instead you want the raw bytes to be encoded into Base64 so you have to pass the optional parameter `$raw_output` too to `md5()` (set to `true`)

```
$md5 = md5($str, true);
```

http://php.net/manual/it/function.md5.php